# Regular Expression results regexp

Tags: regex, expression

```
[(e|x|c)n-t\|]{8}
```

I think the result must have 8 characters and the first one will be e,x or c.

Am I right?

I've tested all possibilites but nothing...

Comment: Can you be specific as to whether you want a specific regex or whether you need an interpretation of the given regex?  (Either way, it is a rather special-purpose question which does run the risk of being closed.  But being specific as to what you want may get you a better answer.)

Comment: Also which language/environment are you using this regex in?

Comment: If you enter your regexp at [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and hover your mouse over the pieces, it explains what they do.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

The earlier answer was for the regex that first appeared in the question, with extra spaces.

The new regex is

```
[(e|x|c)n-t\|]{8}
```

This pattern matches any sequence of 8 characters, where each of the characters is one of:

```
(  e  |  x  c  ) n  o  p  q  r  s  t
```

Within `[` and `]` very few characters need to be escaped, so the `|` and the parentheses you see in there stand for themselves.

It is important to understand that whenever you see `[ ]` then that whole construct matches only ONE character.

If you *want* an 8 character string starting with e, x, or c you can write

```
[exc].{7}
```

which says the first character is e, x, or c, and this is followed by 7 characters.  The `.` generally means any character except a newline, but you can tweak as necessary.

If you want an 8 character string that starts with e, x, or c, then is followed by 7 characters from n-t you can write:

```
[exc][n-t]{7}
```

Comment: Sorry about the spaces, the right REGEX is

[(e|x|c)n-t\|]{8}

Comment: I understand that the first character must be E,X or C. And then there is the N-T and the string must have 8 characters

Comment: But I have no idea of what string might be because of the \]. If you could give me an example of one possible output it would be great!

Comment: So the possible outputs are the combination of e or x or c plus nopqrst in every possible positions?

Comment: Okay I edited the answer.  Your pattern matches many different kinds of things, one of which is "|(((qe(|)".  I've given an example regex for what I think you might like.